# BizTalk 2010 Not Reading dotNET Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk application that works on a DEV environment but not when imported to a TEST environment.

Scenario:

I have 3 dotNET assemblies, a, b and c, plus the BizTalk assembly. We imported the application using an .msi and then manually added the references to a, b and c.

What happens is that BizTalk reads b and c but not a. And by "read" I mean, assemblies b and c's methods are successfully executed but not a's. I know it's not executing a's methods because I log the entry and exit on the methods to the database so I can see when they are used.

Comment: Did you verify Assembly A is in the GAC?

Comment: Yes, all required assemblies are in the GAC

Comment: Check Assembly A's dependencies and ensure that they are present in the test system.

Comment: It turns out there was a problem with the Oracle database in the machine. Once we reinstalled Oracle, the application ran as expected. Thank you for your replies.